# update_repo_cache: true not doing anything

Tags: ansible, github-actions, kubernetes-helm, cert-manager

I have the following ansible tasks that should install cert-manager for github actions to a kubernetes cluster using helm.

```
- name: Add cert-manager repo
  kubernetes.core.helm_repository:
    name: cert-manager
    repo_url: "https://charts.jetstack.io"

- name: Install cert-manager
  kubernetes.core.helm:
    update_repo_cache: true
    release_name: cert-manager
    release_namespace: cert-manager
    name: cert-manager
    namespace: cert-manager
    create_namespace: true
    chart_version: "{{cert_manager_version}}"
    chart_ref: stable/cert-manager
    values:
      prometheus:
        enabled: false
      installCRDs: true
```

However, `update_repo_cache:true` doesn't seem to do anything as I get following output from it.

```
TASK [github-actions : Add cert-manager repo] **********************************
ok: [server3]
[WARNING]: Module did not set no_log for pass_credentials

TASK [github-actions : Install cert-manager] ***********************************
[WARNING]: Both option release_name and its alias name are set.
[WARNING]: Both option release_namespace and its alias namespace are set.
fatal: [server3]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "command": "/usr/local/bin/helm --version=1.8.0 show chart stable/cert-manager", "msg": "Failure when executing Helm command. Exited 1.\nstdout: \nstderr: Error: failed to download \"stable/cert-manager\" at version \"1.8.0\" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)\n", "stderr": "Error: failed to download \"stable/cert-manager\" at version \"1.8.0\" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)\n", "stderr_lines": ["Error: failed to download \"stable/cert-manager\" at version \"1.8.0\" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

The Kubernetes cluster and helm are both working since there are already a lot of other things deployed using helm. Is there something I missed? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing wrong repository in your `chart_ref`, which should be in the format `<repository_name>/<chart_name>`.

Since you are adding Jetstack's repository as `cert-manager` in the first task, so you should use `chart_ref: cert-manager/cert-manager` instead.

Comment: Ohh oops I didn't see that thanks